# Permission to drop views but not drop tables

Tags: mysql, database-permissions

I want to create a user with permission to create and drop views but not drop tables or databases. This is so I can play around when testing my views without the risk of accidentally deleting a table.

There is a `GRANT CREATE VIEW` privilege but there doesn't appear to be a `GRANT DROP VIEW` counterpart. `GRANT DROP` apparently applies to databases, tables and views.

Is this possible in MySQL?

Answer (score 9):

I've been researching this, too, and the answer appears to be No. You can restrict the DROP to only tables/views within one database (or a group of LIKE pattern-matched databases). This will make sure they cannot drop the entire database. Unfortunately, you cannot do pattern-matching on the table/view names. It's either **all** the tables/views (*) in those databases, or **only** explicity mentioned tables/views.

Comment: Good grief, I just checked for MariaDB and the answer STILL appears that you have to GRANT DROP to be able to do views - then you get to drop tables too. Unbelievable.  We were trying to allow a data scientist to build views for a read only production instance and ... it appears I'm forced give them the ability to drop tables in production. Wow!

Comment: I tried "or a group of LIKE pattern-matched databases" and at least with MariaDB, GRANT DROP ON MYDATABASE.Views_* or GRANT DROP ON MYDATABASE.Views_% didn't seem to work either.